# Unable to find fitting selector using scrapy and xpath/css

Tags: html, css, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am currently experimenting with crawlers and how they work.
With that, I am currently stuck finding the right selector call for scrapy - neither xpath nor css works.

Here is the source code:

```
          <body data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.980.0">
             <div id="__next">
              <div class="layout layout--public">
               <section class="container-fluid container-section coach-list-section">
                <div class="single-coach">
                 <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">...</div>
                  <div class="col-md-3 coach-main-content">
                   <div class="coach-info">...</div>
                   <h2>
                    <a href="/de/coach/hermione/20?date=2020-10-25">Name, Age</a>
                   </h2>
```

I want to retrieve the **"Name, Age"**.

With the following code I only get an empty list back but I don't know why:

```
response.xpath('//body/div[contains(@id, "__next")]
/div[contains(@class, "layout layout--public")]
/section[contains(@class, "container-fluid container-section coach-list-section")]
/div[contains(@class, "single-coach")]').getall()
```

*Note: the code is in one line, just for better visualization I entered it in multiple lines.*

---

**EDIT:**
So I used the dev console in the browser and searched for the right xpath which is:

```
//body /div[contains(@id, "__next")] //div[contains(@class, "single-coach")] //div[contains(@class, "main-content")] /h2 /a
```

In the dev console, I can also see the right element highlighted.
Trying this xpath for scrapy doesn't work. I entered the following code in the scrapy shell...

```
response.xpath('//body/div[contains(@id,"__next")]//div[contains(@class,"single-coach")]//div[contains(@class,"main-content")]/h2/a').getall()
```

... and still received and empty list --> []
The ending .getall() should work as the xpath `//body` returns me the wished information.

---

**SECOND EDIT**
The content is loaded dynamically on the website. Hence, I was not able to find the right selector.
For everyone who also has this problem: I suggest to look it up in the scrapy documentation: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
response.xpath('//section//h2/a/text()').getall()
```

Comment: This is a valid answer and would be right if the content is not loaded dynamically. Thanks:)